# Custom return value for new / create ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-models

So I have a model (Photo), where when I call `Photo.new @image => @image` / `Photo.create :image => @image`, I want my model to find an existing photo with the same image hash OR create a new Photo from @image. Assume I can't use `Photo.find_or_initialize_by_hash` because I have a custom find function which finds close copies of images based on a soft image hash.

My first idea was to do

```
before_validation :check_duplicates, :on => :create

def check_duplicates
self = self.find_duplicate
end
```

Unfortunately, I realized you can't just redefine self in a model, so now I think the best approach is doing something along the lines of changing the return value from initialize to the duplicate.

Sort of like this, but it doesn't work (and I've heard horror stories about overriding initialize)

```
def initialize(*params)
super(*params)
return self.find_duplicate || self
end
```

Comment: That'll work in Objective-C, but not in Ruby :) IMHO your best shot is to re-define the Photo.find_or_initialize_by_hash method.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather your model structure looks something like this?

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

If so, you can simply do this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image, :uniq => true
end
```

Or if :image is just an attribute of Photo your first idea was on track:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :check_duplicate

  private
  def check_duplicate
    Photo.where(:image => self.image).count == 0 # will be false if Photo is found
  end
end
```

which will cancel the Photo from being created if #check_duplicate returns false (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Or simply

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :image
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, image is a virtual attribute of photo (paperclip attachment). Photo.find_duplicate is basically Photo.where("BIT_COUNT(phash ^ ?) <= ?", phash, 15). It allows me to search for close duplicates of images (slightly different resolutions / croppings / formats, etc)

Comment: Also, I don't want it to raise an error with validates_uniqueness_of :image, I just want it quietly return the existing photo.

Comment: Then query for the photo before even attempting to save it, also read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. Also pragprog.com has some really good Rails books

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I appreciate the help, but a vague link to the most basic rails tutorial is not very helpful.